# How can I iterate over every character in a given encoding using Python?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

Is there a way to iterate over every character in a given encoding, and print it's code? Say, UTF8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Unicode characters can be represented in `UTF-n` for all defined `n`. What are you trying to achieve?

If you really want to do something like print all the valid characters in a particular encoding, without needing to know whether the encoding is "single byte" or "multi byte" or whether its size is fixed or not:

```
import unicodedata as ucd
import sys

def dump_encoding(enc):
    for i in xrange(sys.maxunicode):
        u = unichr(i)
        try:
            s = u.encode(enc)
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            continue
        try:
            name = ucd.name(u)
        except:
            name = '?'
        print "U+%06X %r %s" % (i, s, name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dump_encoding(sys.argv[1])
```

Suggestions: Try it out on something small, like `cp1252`. Redirect stdout to a file.

Answer (score 6):

dude, do you have any idea how many code points there are in unicode...

btw, from the Python docs:

> [**chr**( *i* )](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr)
>
> Return the string representing a character whose Unicode code point is the integer *i*. For example, `chr(97)` returns the string `'a'`, while `chr(8364)` returns the string `'€'`. This is the inverse of [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord).
>
> The valid range for the argument is from 0 through 1,114,111 (0x10FFFF in base 16). `ValueError` will be raised if *i* is outside that range.

So

```
import sys

for i in range(sys.maxunicode + 1):
    char = chr(i)
    print(repr(char))  # print('\ud800') causes a UnicodeEncodeError
```

Comment: That's why I don't wanna do it by hand :)

Comment: You don't want to do it automatically either, it's over one million characters, it'd take a tree to print that, in fact it's called the unicode standard book ;)

Comment: So, don't print it :) Not all of our computers are connected directly to a line printer anymore :) Over a million?! You'd need some kind of machine, like a computer, to handle that much data! :)

Answer (score 1):

For single-byte encodings you can use:

```
''.join(chr(x) for x in range(256)).decode(encoding, 'ignore')
```

to get a string containing all the valid characters in the given encoding.

For fixed-size multibyte encodings careful use of `struct.pack()` in place of `chr()` should work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using python3.7

```
import unicodedata as ucd
import sys

def dump_encoding(enc):
    for i in range(sys.maxunicode):
        u = chr(i)
        try:
            s = u.encode(enc)
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            continue
        try:
            name = ucd.name(u)
        except:
            name = '?'
        print (i, s, u, name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.getdefaultencoding()
    dump_encoding(sys.argv[1])
```

Make sure you are using correct version of python to run the script, and one argument is required:

```
python3.7 ./iterate_over_charset.py utf-8 > unicode_all.txt
```

Sample output:

```
4473 b'\xe1\x85\xb9' ᅹ HANGUL JUNGSEONG YA-YO
4474 b'\xe1\x85\xba' ᅺ HANGUL JUNGSEONG EO-O
4475 b'\xe1\x85\xbb' ᅻ HANGUL JUNGSEONG EO-U
4476 b'\xe1\x85\xbc' ᅼ HANGUL JUNGSEONG EO-EU
4477 b'\xe1\x85\xbd' ᅽ HANGUL JUNGSEONG YEO-O
4478 b'\xe1\x85\xbe' ᅾ HANGUL JUNGSEONG YEO-U
4479 b'\xe1\x85\xbf' ᅿ HANGUL JUNGSEONG O-EO
4480 b'\xe1\x86\x80' ᆀ HANGUL JUNGSEONG O-E
4481 b'\xe1\x86\x81' ᆁ HANGUL JUNGSEONG O-YE
```